# How can i pass a parameter to a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js

I just got started to Vue and i'm trying to understand some basic concepts such as conditional rendering and how to pass data from where i load the app to a component. Suppose i'm  rendering a Vue component like this:

```
<div id="app">
    <myComponent></myComponent>
</div>
```

Suppose `myComponent` looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
  
    <h1>First block</h1>

    </h1>Second block</h1>

  </div>
</template>
```

I want to be able to render `First block` or `Second block` when i load the Vue app according to a parameter i pass to the component, like:

```
<div id="app">
    <myComponent id="first"></myComponent>
</div>
```

In this case i should see `First block`, whereas if instead of `id="first"` there was `id="second"` the output was supposed to be `Second block`. How can i do this?

I know it's a very basic question, but most of the sources i found explained how to do the opposite. Any kind of advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vue you could pass [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) (parameters) to component which defines this ones in its script like :

```
<template>
  <div>
  
    <h1 v-if="block==='first'">First block</h1>

    </h1 v-else>Second block</h1>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
  props:{
    block:{
       type:String, 
        default:'first'
     }
  }
}
</script>
```

in parent component pass the prop like :

```
<div id="app">
    <myComponent block="first"></myComponent>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="app">
    <myComponent block="second"></myComponent>
</div>
```